# Recursive seqence of power set, starting with the empty set

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_0$ be the empty set and $A_n := \mathcal{P}(A_{n-1})$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I have to determine $A_n$ and $|A_n|$.

Using the definition of the power set I get 
\begin{align}
A_1 & = \left\{ \emptyset \right\} & |A_1| = 1 \\
A_2 & = \left\{ \emptyset, \left\{ \emptyset \right\} \right\} & |A_2| = 2 \\
A_3 & = \left\{ \emptyset, \left\{ \emptyset \right\}, \left\{ \left\{ \emptyset \right\} \right\}, \left\{ \emptyset, \left\{ \emptyset \right\} \right\} \right\} & |A_3| = 4
\end{align}

and so on. Since $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}$, the cardinality of $|A_n|$ is determined by the sequence
\begin{align}
|A_0| & = 0 \\
|A_n| & = 2^{|A_{n-1}|} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
So with a (clumsy) dot notation, $|A_n| = 2^{2^{2^{\vdots^{2^0}}}}$.

However, I did not find any explicit form of either sequences (which is somewhat suggested by the formulation *"determine $A_n$ and $|A_n|$"*).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your answer is entirely correct. You've determined $|A_n|$; it's just an accident of mathematical history that there isn't a neater notation for the answer. The same is true for $A_n$.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss thanks, that was what I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Weiss [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710580/recursive-seqence-of-power-set-starting-with-the-empty-set/1086800#comment1487192_710580) in the comments:

> Your answer is entirely correct. You've determined $|A_n|$; it's just an accident of mathematical history that there isn't a neater notation for the answer. The same is true for $A_n$.

Answer (score 3):

The operation that computes $|A_n|$ is known as tetration. It has many notations. Here I show its definition using two different notations:
$$^na = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } n=0 \\ a^{\left(^{(n-1)}a\right)} &\text{if } n>0 \end{cases} $$
$$a\uparrow\uparrow n = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } n=0 \\ a^{a\uparrow\uparrow(n-1)} &\text{if } n>0 \end{cases} $$

Basically, tetration is a power tower where $a$ is repeated $n$ times.

According to Wikipedia, the first notation is used by Maurer[1901], Goodstein[1947] and Rudy Rucker[1982]. The second notation is known as Knuth's up-arrow notation[1976]. See this wiki about tetration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Using tetration we have:
$$|A_n| =  {^{n-1}2} = 2\uparrow\uparrow(n-1)$$

It is interesting to note how fast this sequence grows:
$$ \begin{align*}
   &|A_0| = {^{-1}2} = 0 \small \qquad \text{ (extending the definition)}\\
   &|A_1| = {^02} = 1 \\
   &|A_2| = {^12} = 2 \\
   &|A_3| = {^22} = 4 \\
   &|A_4| = {^32} = 16 \\
   &|A_5| = {^42} = 65536 \\
   &|A_6| = {^52} = 200352...9156736 \small \qquad \text{ (19729 digits in total in base 10)} \\
   &|A_7| = {^62} = 2^{200352...9156736} \approx 10^{6.03\cdot 10^{19727} }\approx 10^{10^{19727.78}} \\
   &...
  \end{align*}
   $$